# How to declare new operator using the class template in c++

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I have a template class (Word):

```
template<int C>
class Word {
...
}
```

I want to add an operator:

```
friend Word<C> operator&(Word<C>& word1, Word<C>& word2);   // & operator between all bits
```

so now I have:

```
template<int C>
class Word {
   ...
   friend Word<C> operator&(Word<C>& word1, Word<C>& word2);    // & operator between all bits
}

template<int C>
Word<C> operator&(Word<C>& word1, Word<C>& word2) {
    Word<C> ans = new Word<C>;

    for (int i = 0; i < C; i++) {
        ans[i] = word1[i] & word2[i];
    }
    return ans;
}
```

but I get this markers:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template has already been declared and add <> after the function name 
     here)
    - friend declaration 'Word<C> operator&(Word<C>&, Word<C>&)' declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]
```

and this error when using the operator:

```
undefined reference to `operator&(Word<8>&, Word<8>&)'
```

using code:

```
Word<C> tmp1 = (words[i] & mask);
```

Comment: Where do you declare words[i] and mask? also you have a memory leak in the operator implementation. And you return a pointer to a Word<C> but the return type is Word<C>. Does that compile?

Comment: `Word<C> ans = new Word<C>;` should be `Word<C> ans;`

Answer (score 1):

Declare the function function first before you make it a friend.

```
// Forward declare the class.
template<int C> class Word;

// Declare the function.
template<int C> Word<C> operator&(Word<C>& word1, Word<C>& word2);
```

Then, the `friend` declaration in the class should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the fact that you are not declaring a member `operator&` overload so the resulting declaration is not templated. If you compile with `g++` you see a useful warning message related to this:

```
test4.cpp:4:60: warning: friend declaration ‘Word<C> operator&(Word<C>&, Word<C>&)’ declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]
test4.cpp:4:60: note: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template has already been declared and add <> after the function name here) 
test4.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
```

Telling you that the friend declaration inside the class actually does not declare a template function.

To fix this just template the `operator&` itself. Here is a fully working example (note `T != U`):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<int T>
class Word {
  public:
    template<int C>
    friend Word<C> operator&(Word<C>& word1, Word<C>& word2);
};

template<int C>
Word<C> operator&(Word<C>& word1, Word<C>& word2){
  Word<C> ans;
  std::cout << C << std::endl;
  // TODO add your stuff here
  return ans;
}

int main() {
  Word<8> a, b;
  Word<8> c = a & b;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ g++ test4.cpp && ./a.out
Inside operator &
8
```